# php fails to create and assign array

Tags: php, arrays, session, assign

In PHP is it posible to have an array where a string was previously stored?

```
echo "valuebefore: ".$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE];
$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] = "somestring";

echo "typebefore: ".gettype($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE]);
$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] = array();

echo "typeafter: ".gettype($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE]);
if (!is_array($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE]))
{
  echo "is not an array";
}
echo "valueafter: ".$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE];
```

and the output is:

```
valuebefore: A
typebefore: string 
typeafter: string   << the type didnt change to array!
is not an array
valueafter: A       << the value was not updated!
```

Why can't it just hold the new array?
How come the value has not changed either?

**Edit:**

Here is the vardump for other variables involved:

```
echo var_dump(TL_MODE)." <br/>";
echo var_dump($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])." <br/>";
echo var_dump($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE])." <br/>";
```

output:

```
string(2) "FE"
string(32) "A96665c9f1e41d1745bf3a3d75cff33a"
string(1) "A"
```

Comment: Here it works correctly: valuebefore: 
typebefore: string
typeafter: array
valueafter: Array

Comment: Could it be some PHP configuration possibly?

Comment: Can you try doing this with normal `arrays` and not `session`? Looks like your session may be the issue. It works correctly for me too using session.

Comment: Maybe. But are you sure that you are running the right script? I mean maybe you've saved in other place and you are running the old one :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brent Baisley is right on that $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'] is not an array it's a string, but the base problem turned out to be a cookie related issue that was corrupting the $_SESSION data.

As soon as I cleared cookies and cache in the web browser all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of TL_MODE? If you didn't define that as a constant then you're just adding array items. Which would explain the behavior your are seeing. Output the array at the end and see what you have.

```
var_dump($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN']);
```

Comment: I added the the vardumps in the question above. Thanks.

Comment: seems like your problem is that $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'] is not an array, it's a string. So you are trying to add/reference an array item on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Output of the following code attached:

- valuebefore: A
- typebefore: string
- typeafter: array
- valueafter: Array

You should echo the value of TL_MODE and $_SESSION contents for debugging.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    DEFINE('TL_MODE', 'tl_mode_constant');
    $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] = 'A';

    echo "valuebefore: ".$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] . '<br />';
    $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] = "somestring";

    echo "typebefore: ".gettype($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE]) . '<br />';
    $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] = array();

    echo "typeafter: ".gettype($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE]);
    if (!is_array($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE])){
        echo "is not an array" . '<br />';
    }
    echo "valueafter: ".$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE] . '<br />';

?>
```

Comment: I added the the vardump for TL_MODE and $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'] in the question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This smaller example works for me:

```
$ php -r '$a="foo"; $a=array("bar"); var_dump($a);'
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Your var_dumps should show that (1) `$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN']` is an array, and (2) that your constant, `TL_MODE` is a non-null value.  If it's null, then `$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][TL_MODE]` is the same as `$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'][]`, and you're only adding array elements when you think you're reassigning.  But if `$_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN']` is a string, then you can't add subscriptsas if it was an array.